# Entity Framework 6 DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, dbeaver

I have a Winforms application (running on .NET 4.8) and Entity Framework 6.

Calling `context.SaveChanges();` throws a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` after adding collection of new elements.

`factPeriods` is a collection of new elements.

```
using (FactContext context = new FactContext(connection.ConnectionString))
{
    context.Bastion_FactPeriods.AddRange(factPeriods);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is my table in code:

```
[Table(nameof(Bastion_FactPeriods))]
public partial class Bastion_FactPeriods
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID_Branch { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID_Area { get; set; }

    public int TN { get; set; }

    public DateTime Time_begin { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time_end { get; set; }

    public int Time_value { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Used { get; set; }

    public bool? OnlyEntrance { get; set; }
}
```

[image: This is my table in DBeaver]

Comment: what is the value of `factPeriods.ID`? you have to make sure that you are passing ID while saving

Comment: ID == 0, but this is normal, because the entity is not stored in the DB yet or am I wrong?

Comment: your screenshot should be in English for us to understand it. and in your screenshot it's not clear that you have ID as an identity column

Comment: Column "Идентичность" mean Indentity. ID is identity. 
Column "Not N.." mean Not Null.

Comment: What exactly is the error here ?

Comment: i finded what causes the exception. Composite unique key (TN, Time_begin, Time_value) exists in this table.
EF throws exception after try adding new row with equals composite key but with different identificator